# how to get data generated by biometric machine into asp.net

Tags: c#

I have client requirement in which client wants to get output data of bio metric machine and want to process in asp.net c#. How to get Data from bio metric machine and process int asp.net?

Comment: We need more details, what is the machine, what kind of communication does it use? USB, Serial? I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes, The biometric attendence machine is connected to software USB. I want to take a data line punch time,date,whose punch, to use this data to into ERP

Comment: Do you have information about the device, such as the manufacturer and model number? Good chance there is a datasheet that will give us information on how to interface with it.

Comment: javascript based fingerprint scanner API documentation is available at http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html. Check if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very generic so here's a very generic answer.

Generally speaking processing data in asp.net consists of:

- Creating controllers with HttpGet, HttPost methods
- Saving data into a data store (e.g. a database)

There are many questions you need to ask before you come up with a good design. For example:

- How much data?
- How often?
- How would the data be consumed (via an API by a 3rd party app?, published somewhere?
- Would you be using an existing datastore?
- What authentication and authorization requirements need to be met?
- (Many, many more questions.)

One place to find samples for aps.net is https://github.com/aspnet/samples

As an example, *if your data comes in as json*, you could look at [JsonUploadSample](https://github.com/aspnet/samples/tree/master/samples/aspnet/WebApi/JsonUploadSample):

> This sample illustrates how to upload and download JSON to and from an ApiController.

Good luck!